# Shapefile created in QGIS does not fit in eCognition project

Tags: qgis, shapefile, ecognition

I have various shapefiles - some created by others, some created by my self. They should all have the same size of the underlying Raster file.

The shapefiles have been created on top of a Raster file (in QGIS) with Coordinate System WGS84 /UTM zone 45N. I checked the Options in QGIS - Shapes and Raster use the same Coordinate System.

When importing the Shapefiles to Erdas Imagine, everything looks fine.

In eCognition the shapefiles doesn't fit to the extend of the Raster file.

Where can I solve this problem? Do I have to change something in QGIS or is it a eCognition problem?

[image: Shapefile created in QGIS - Displayed in eCognition]

Comment: For which purpose you need to process the shape file in eCognition?

Comment: I have some sample points that I want to use for classification. So I do a coarse multi resolution segmentation first. Than I do a second segmentation with a Threshold of "Num. of overlap samples (Thematic Objects) >0"

Comment: if you want to use use shapefile for classification do the chessboard segmentation as i said already and use geometrical parameters to classify the image objects

Comment: Thank you for this information, maybe my question was not very exact. My problem is, that the imported shapefile is not congruent to the raster file.

Comment: did you check your planar units of your shape file is same as in your image?

Comment: Yes I did several checking, also build up of project from scratch. I think it is a display error from the Subset Window of eCognition. Because in Workspace, a Polygon-Shapefile was displayed correct - according to your approach. I will try again with Point-Shapefile how things work.

Comment: don't look at subset window, because it only shows how many layers did you add. It may not be correct in your case.

Comment: if you got result, let me know how did you do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not directly view the shape file in eCognition. But you can use the shape file in the process.

Import the shape as 'Thematic layer'. If you want to use the shape file to segment the image, use chessboard segmentation with the object size more than your image file and select 'yes' to select which shape file you want to use in the place of 'Thematic layer usage'. Execute the process. If you want use the shape file for other application, use that in the process when writing rule set. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Problem solved: The subset selection window simulates wrong extend of the imported Thematic Layers. However this was irritating me, and I could not check with my point-shapefile. Some test with polygon shapefile (like your explanation) delivered answer. Shapefile was at exactly the right place.